# What's the correct way to write a generic extension method that can be called on any IEnumerable (including an IQueryable)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, generics

I've got some static functions that encapsulate common DB operations that we perform.

Example:

```
public static IQueryable<Round> FilterByStandardExclusionCriteria(
  this IQueryable<Round> rounds,
  bool someExclusionFlag = true,
  bool otherExclusionFlag = true,
)
{
  return (
    from round in rounds
    where (
      // Filter down the list of rounds based on exclusion flags
    )
    select round
  );
}
```

This usually works perfectly, but sometimes the LINQ translation to SQL fails and we have to explicitly enable client-side evaluation of the LINQ query *before* some of the functions get called.

I rewrote the extension methods as generics, which ended up looking something like this:

```
public static T FilterByStandardExclusionCriteria<T>(
  this T rounds,
  bool someExclusionFlag = true,
  bool otherExclusionFlag = true,
) where T : IEnumerable<Round>
{
  return (
    from round in rounds
    where (
      // Filter down the list of rounds based on exclusion flags
    )
    select round
  );
}
```

But doing so gives me a compiler error saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Namespace.Round>' to 'T'.

I tried to explicitly cast the return value to T with `(T)return ...`, but doing so results in the following exception being thrown at runtime:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[Namespace.Round]' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[Namespace.Round]'.'

What's the correct way to write a generic extension method that can be called on any IEnumerable?

Comment: Use `IQueryable<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`, and ensure you use `Expression<Func<>>` instead of raw `Func<>`.

Comment: "sometimes the LINQ translation to SQL fails and we have to explicitly enable client-side evaluation of the LINQ query" sounds like a bad idea. You should probably try to solve the translation first.

Comment: @Charlieface totally agree with you there, but sometimes the solution *is* to enable explicit client-side evaluation of the query, right?

If translation fails on a complex query, and I determine that the reason that translation failed is because part of the query involves an expression with un-translatable business logic, isn't the correct course of action to structure the query so that the business logic happens as late as possible, then switch to client evaluation before running that portion?

Comment: @Dai Where are you seeing a usage of `Func<>`? Can you go into that any more? I am using an argument of type Func<> in related code, is my error related to that?

Comment: Not necessarily, sometimes the solution is to rethink the business logic so that it *can* be done server-side. I'm doubtful that's been done: most of the time this happens when someone decides to refactor the logic into functions, which doesn't work with EF translation, etc. Yes, if it's not possible then the only option is client-side evalution

Comment: Either way, the real issue here is that you need to change your constraint `where T : IQueryable<Round>` if you want server-side evaluation, or you need to just remove the generics and do `public static IEnumerable<T> FilterByStandardExclusionCriteria<T>` if you want client-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave `FilterByStandardExclusionCriteria` as is (with IQueryable type) and call it like that:

```
enumerableCollection.AsQueryable().FilterByStandardExclusionCriteria()
```

Comment: Oh wow, just looked into this. Seems like exactly what I need. In general, I’m curious about why the generics approach isn’t working. Why would I even need to cast the return result if the query statement returns the same type as the input, which is guaranteed to be the same as the return type?

Comment: Your rewritten function will work too if you declare it as `public static IEnumerable<T> FilterByStandardExclusionCriteria<T>(
  this IEnumerable<T> rounds...`